# definiteinteggral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, contest-math, contour-integration

The integral is given by 
$$\int_0^1 \frac{\ln (1-x)\ln x}{1+x} dx = \frac{1}{8}\big(-\pi^2\ln(4) +13\zeta(3)\big).$$
Any ideas how to prove?  We cannot solve the integral so easily because we cannot use a power series approach or harmonic series generating function since the denominator and numerator of the integrand are different.  You will see convergence problems if we try using the power series for $\ln(1-x)$ and $(1+x)^{-1}$ to integrate term by term, thus this method does not work here as in other cases.
Substitution of the form $x=e^t$ yields
$$
\int_{-\infty}^0 \frac{t\cdot e^t\ln(1-e^t)}{1+e^t}dt.
$$
This integral does not seem to be trivial either however.  The Riemann zeta function is
$$
\zeta(3)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-3}.
$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the geometric series for $\frac{1}{1+x}$, we can write

\begin{align*}
I := \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\log(1-x)\log x}{1+x} \, dx
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1} \int_{0}^{1} x^{n-1} \log (1-x) \log x \, dx \\
&= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n-1} \cdot \frac{1}{n} \left( \frac{H_{n}}{n} - \zeta(2) + H_{n}^{(2)} \right),
\end{align*}

where $H_{n}^{(s)} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} k^{-s}$ is the generalized harmonic number. Introducing the *alternating Euler sum* as

$$ A_{p}^{(s)} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}H_{n}^{(s)}}{n^{p}}, $$

we can write

$$ I = A_{2}^{(1)} + A_{1}^{(2)} - \zeta(2)\log 2. $$

Now it is relatively well-known that

$$ A_{1}^{(2)} = \zeta(3) - \frac{1}{2}\zeta(2)\log 2
\quad \text{and} \quad
A_{2}^{(1)} = \frac{5}{8}\zeta(3). $$

(There are several ways of proving these identities. I proved them using dilogarithm and trilogarithm, but I also saw solutions using complex analysis. See [here](http://sos440.tistory.com/200) for my old approach.)

Therefore we have

$$ I = \frac{13}{8}\zeta(3) - \frac{3}{2}\zeta(2)\log 2. $$

---

**Addendum.** Using partial fraction expansion, you can check that

$$ \frac{1}{k(n+k)^{2}} = \frac{1}{n^{2}} \left( \frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{k+n} \right) - \frac{1}{n(k+n)^{2}}. $$

So it follows that

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{1} x^{n-1} \log (1-x) \log x \, dx
&= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k(n+k)^{2}} \\
&= \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^{2}} \left( \frac{1}{k} - \frac{1}{k+n} \right) - \frac{1}{n(k+n)^{2}} \\
&= \frac{H_{n}}{n^{2}} - \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n+k)^{2}} \\
&= \frac{H_{n}}{n^{2}} - \frac{1}{n} \zeta(2) + \frac{H_{n}^{(2)}}{n}.
\end{align*}

Comment: It is very nice solutions thanks much a lot  for your time..But, why is it that the line 1 and line 2 are equality?  I followed your steps and write the taylor series for $\ln(1-x)$ as well in the integral and obtain 
$$
I=\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^{n-1} \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k(n+k)^2}
$$
I am unsure how you got Harmonic sum and broke up that sum into a few to get the $\zeta(2)$ term, etc.  Thanks again!!

Comment: @Jeff That's quite a coincidence the the two Euler sums are the two sums from the other two integrals. And he differentiated the beta function.  It's explained on his web site.

Comment: @RandomVariable Thanks for your explanations....Yes that integral was quite interesting.  I have many many more to post!   Thanks for the addition to the post sos44o, so clear!!!!  Upvote!

Comment: @sos440 With regard to the addendum,  I'm assuming that series on the right side of the equation comes from using the series definitions of the digamma and trigamma functions after twice differentiating the beta function and letting $z=n$ and $w = 1$. If that's the case, couldn't you instead use the fact that  $\psi(n) = - \gamma + H_{n-1}$ and $\psi_{1}(n) = \zeta(2) - H_{n-1}^{(2)}$?

Comment: @RandomVariable That's a possible approach. In my personal experience, however, manipulating in summation level was relatively easier.